# Query with Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I have the following data base model:
[image]
I use Linq-to-SQL and Design Pattern Repository as describe the fallowing page http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/

this is a classes diagram :

[image]

I want make a query like this but using instead Repository Design Pattern

```
ExampleRepositoryDataSet data = new ExampleRepositoryDataSet();
var query = from hotel in data.Hotel
            join category in data.Category on hotel.Category equals category.IdCategory
            join country in data.Country on hotel.Contry equals country.IdContry
            where country.Name == "Cuba"
            orderby hotel.Rating descending
            group new {hotel, category, country} by category.Name;
```

Comment: The pattern you are using is good when dealing with single entity access scenarios. Not so much when you have to compose across multiple entities. There's no right answer to where you should host the query you mention, but an orchestration layer that handles these types of concerns would be a good start. You can still use your individual repositories to access all the Hotel, Category and Country data inside your orchestration layer. Best of luck.

Comment: @RobEpstein Thank you for your help,Then you advise me to add data source and use the ExampleRepositoryDataSet object to the query.I could use the Query Object Pattern?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel What I want to do is a query with Repository Design Pattern like I did with ExamplesRepositoryDataSet? Or can I use the Query Object Pattern?Im using linq-to sql and Repository Design Pattern to add data and connect to a data source to make queries Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
public class HotelRepository : EFRepository<Hotel>, IHotelRepository
{
     public List<IGrouping<string, Hotel>> GetAllByCountrynameOrderedByCountrynameAndGroupedByCategoryname(string categoryName, string countryName)
     {
          return DbSet
              .Where(hotel => hotel.Country.Name.Equals(countryName))
              .OrderByDescending(hotel => hotel.Rating)
              .GroupBy(hotel => hotel.Category.Name)
              .ToList();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `Repository` hides your ORM (Linq-2-SQL, which is also obsolete, it's better to use EF), that is  Repository contains reference to ORM-presented dataset, `ExampleRepositoryDataSet` as I can see.
2. `Repository` is often described in terms of `Add, Delete, Edit, ListAll` methods, thus its implementation can (and have to) use Linq-2-SQL abilities for query construction. It's what you are doing.
3. You can populate your `Repository` with method `ListHotelsByCountryNameAndOrder(string countryName, bool isAsc)` and implement it in the way you've just written.
4. If you want to use `generic repository` (someone tells that it's anti-pattern, but I disagree), your problem becomes more difficult but still stays solvable. Take a look at `Specification` pattern.
5. Finally, `Query Object Pattern` is a bit outdated. Today .NET expressions seems to be good alternative. For simple filtering you may populate your repository with method `IEnumerable<T> ListAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)` and use it like `myRepo.ListAll(t => t.Name == "Cuba")`. For complex queries it's a better way to add new method (3.) or use Specification (4.)
6. Don't return `IQueryable` from repository. Always call `.ToList()` or another non-lazy operation to load data.